# How can I use windows 7 styles for an Excel 2007 VBA UserForm?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have an Excel 2007 VBA spreadsheet that displays a UserForm. Works fine on Windows XP, but when I run it on windows 7, the form shows in the old Windows XP style rather than the new Windows 7 style. 
   Is there an easy way to make the VBA userForm show up with the correct OS style?

Comment: Hi Tav, It should turn automaticly.  In wich format you saved the file?

Answer (score 2):

Check whether you have an `excel.exe.manifest` file in your office installation folder on your Win 7 system. If this is missing, then this can affect how winforms are displayed via VBA - please take a look here for more information: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=KB%3bEN-US%3b309366

EDIT: The above linked page was removed by Microsoft some time after 2014/06/06. However, it can be viewed at the Internet Archive (in Spanish/en Español)...
https://web.archive.org/web/20140606115708/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309366

Comment: From the referenced KB article above....
If you enable a Windows XP theme in Visual Basic 6.0, you may encounter unexpected behavior. For example, if you place option buttons on top of a Frame control and then enable a Windows XP theme or visual style, the option buttons on the Frame control appear as black blocks when you run the executable file.